# Capturing jquery form data

Tags: php, jquery, jformer

I'm using JFormer to create a form, and can view the data using json_encode($formValues) but I can't capture the $formValues on the server.

```
   var fvalue = <?php json_encode($formValues) ?>;
   var ftarget = "http://home.server.com/regcreate.php?data=";
   var a = document.createElement("script");
   a.type = "text/javascript";
   a.src = ftarget + fvalue;
   document.body.appendChild(a);
```

If value is simple, this works.  If I try to send json_encode($formValues) it does not work.  It doesn't sent anything.  Am I going about this the correct way?  Can I maybe use Jquery serialize function instead of json_encode?

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you are using Jquery, You can serialize form and submit usin ajax form POST. Please be aware that it is not PHP serialize object, you can access the form values as normal $_POST

```
$('#btnId').click(function () {       

    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url: "regcreate.php",

        //GET method is used
        type: "POST",

        data: $("#Form").serialize(),
        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,

        //success
        success: function (html) {             
            //assuming that pgp page returns value boolean value
            if (html=='1') {                 
                //add success message
            } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');              
        }      
    });
});
```